# "before each hook for" during running hardhat test

Tags: solidity, erc-721, typescript

ive just started learning solidity and I tried to make a contract and encounter error during running hardhat test .

```
 1) FortuneTigersPunk
   "before each" hook for "should deploy successfully":
 Error: too many arguments:  in Contract constructor (count=4, expectedCount=0, code=UNEXPECTED_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
  at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:225:28)
  at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:237:20)
  at Logger.checkArgumentCount (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:303:18)
  at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1227:16)
  at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
  at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
  at C:\Users\loobj\hardhat-tutorial\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at __awaiter (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
  at ContractFactory.deploy (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:1132:16)
```

below is my test script :

```
describe("FortuneTigersPunk", async () => {
  let FTPContract: Contract;
  let owner: SignerWithAddress;
  let alice: SignerWithAddress;

  beforeEach(async () => {
     const FTPFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("TigerNft") ;
    [owner, alice] = await ethers.getSigners();

    FTPContract = await FTPFactory.deploy(
      "FortuneTigersPunk",
      "FTP",
      10000,
      1
    );
    console.log(`owner: ${owner.address} alice: ${alice.address}`);

   });
   it("should deploy successfully", async() => {
    console.log("contract address", FTPContract.address);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: `too many arguments`. This means that your constructor expects 0 arguments (or maybe the contract doesn't have a constructor at all) but you are providing it with 4 arguments.

So either fix your contract or fix your deployment. The constructor is called once, only during deployment, so you have to give it the right amount of arguments.

Comment: tq for your advise~